# The philosophical analysis of creating and implementing good ideas?

Tags: teleology, idea, normativity, action

There are projects with great ideas, but poor implementation; and there are mediocre ideas, but are well implemented.

**What sort of philosophy and which philosophers, if any, address this phenomenon?**

Comment: [Project management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_management)?

Comment: Well, translating ideas to action is teleological, so any philosophical discourse related to conceptual analysis, teleology, and action theory would certainly broadly represent. Here's an article out of SEP that invokes a FOL formalism stit( ), "see-to-it-that": [Logic of Action](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-action/). More generally [Action (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/action/). Good is also a question of being [normative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normativity), and SEP has this on [normativity of ideas](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/meaning-normativity/).

Comment: Ultimately, your topic is rather focused, so if you poke around at [PhilPapers](https://philpapers.org/) using the terms above, you might find something of interest.